# Paragraph ended before \@tempa was complete

Tags: graphics

Error warning:

```
Runaway argument?

"vt.eps" \edef \Gin@ext {\Gin@sepdefault \filename@ext }\ifx \Gin@ext \ETC.

! File ended while scanning use of \@tempa.

<inserted text> 

   \par 

<*> ./try.tex
```

?

Platform, Windows7-64bit, WinEdt 10.3, downloading packages by miktex

Problem occurred when I renewed the most recent released version of miktex(include its packages, 2019.11.29 today), while it runs without error on my friend's computer which has the same platform and software as mine but hadn't been renewed for a long time. Codes as follows(codes are written in a file named as 'try.tex' with 'vt.eps' picture file in the same path):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
   \centering
  \includegraphics[width=5cm]{vt.eps}
  \caption{vt}\label{fig:vt}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: Ensure that your miktex is really up-to-date by checking for updates in user and admin mode. If the problem persists show the log-file